# Identify a building applying SURF/SIFT algorithm on it's picture and obtain GPS coordinates

Tags: android, opencv, sift, surf, google-goggles

I would like to extract the SURF/SIFT feature points from a picture of a building or a landmark and identify its GPS coordinates.

I'm using OpenCV for Android for SURF.

I would like to know if there's an API which returns the GPS coordinates of the building in the picture, I can do any kind of transformations on the picture before sending out to the server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the camera, longitude and latitude are attached to your photo’s EXIF information.
[Exiv2](http://www.exiv2.org/) is a C++ library and a command line utility to manage image metadata.
With several images of same building, extracting SURF and calibrating cameras (images) you can retrieve "exact" coordinate in the reference world. Is that what you achieve to do ?

Comment: Hi Eric, Although that's what I'm required to do, I was wondering if there's an online API or service which has a database of Pictures of buildings and their address/Coordinates. (Like Google goggles, but with an API set). Thank you for you help. :)

Comment: The databases I used some years ago were not free but you can try to google "Terra Numerica project", which goal was the digitization of urban. Remember how this site works: [accepting answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)